# Testing custom exception with NUnit

Tags: c#, exception, nunit

I'm having trouble testing my custom Exception with NUnit. For context, I'm building a simple airport program to improve C#, which I started learning recently. Planes can't land in the airport if it's stormy or if the airport is full. Extracts of the relevant code:

Extract from Airport class with Exceptions:

```
 public void Land(Plane plane)
        {
            try
            {
                if (weather.Forecast() == "stormy")
                {
                    throw new StormyException("It's too stormy to land");
                }
                if (planes.Count >= _Capacity)
                {
                    throw new CapacityException("Airport is full");
                }
                planes.Add(plane);
                Console.WriteLine($"{ plane.Name } has landed at {_AirportName}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Example of the Exceptions themselves:

```
   class StormyException : Exception
    {

        public StormyException(string message)
           : base(String.Format(message))
        {

        }

    }
```

Example of a failing test:

```
   [Test]

        public void PlaneWontLandIfStormy()
        {
            var weather = new Mock<Weather>();
            weather.Setup(x => x.Forecast()).Returns("stormy");
            var airport = new Airport("TestAirport", weather.Object, 10);
            var exception = Assert.Throws<Exception>(() => airport.Land(plane));
            Assert.AreEqual(exception.Message, "It's too stormy to land");
        }
```

When I run the program, everything works fine. However this test does not pass, with this error: `Expected: <System.Exception> But was: null`. I have looked into this and seen syntax along the lines of `[ExpectedException]`... but I cannot seem to solve the problem. I'm very new to C# so any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Exception handling is a pet peeve of mine, and you have some seriosu issues with your exception handling there. I hope this was just for testing, but to be on the safe side I will link my favourite two articles that explain how to do it properly: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Comment: You are consuming the exception so there is nothing to catch outside of that method

Comment: Thanks @Christopher - I'll read those articles. Oh no :( I thought I had done alright at handling the exceptions - can you elaborate what the serious issues are? (no need to go into detail - I'll read the articles - just would be interested to know what immediately jumps out at you as so bad?)

Comment: @jordantomiko I link those articles a lot, as those are common beginners mistakes. The biggest mistake I see is 'catch (Exception ex)' - you catch to wide. Followed by `Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);` - you only expose the message.

Comment: @Christopher thank you for taking the time to explain that and share the articles - as a C# beginner, much appreciated. I'm mostly using them here to practice error handling syntax and so this is very helpful. (To be honest, if I was writing this program "in real life" I wouldn't throw Exceptions for the circumstances as they aren't really "exceptional")

Comment: @jordantomiko Actually if this was a producitve simulated Airport, this would not be a bad pattern. For the planes at least, the Weather and Plane Capacity are examples for "Exogenous" exceptions. Even if they did check the value themself, it could change by the time they try to land.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Land` method need to throw the exception, not catch it.

```
public void Land(Plane plane)
{
    if (weather.Forecast() == "stormy")
    {
        throw new StormyException("It's too stormy to land");
    }
    if (planes.Count >= _Capacity)
    {
        throw new CapacityException("Airport is full");
    }
    planes.Add(plane);
    Console.WriteLine($"{ plane.Name } has landed at {_AirportName}");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**in your test**

var exception = Assert.Throws<**StormyException** >(() => airport.Land(plane));
Assert.AreEqual(exception.Message, "It's too stormy to land");

**or**

var exception = Assert.Throws<**StormyException** >(() => airport.Land(plane));
exception.Message.Equals("It's too stormy to land");